# Get the nodeValue for a tag

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I am trying to get the nodeValue of any tag found in  an html page but am getting an error and i can't figure what is causing that error. Fatal error: **Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::getElementByTagName() in C:\xampplite\htdocs\msite\getscriptnodeValue.php on line 5**..here is my code..Can anyone please help me??Thnxx in advance.

```
    $file=file_get_contents('test.txt');
$doc=new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">'.$file);
$data=$doc->getElementByTagName('div');
for($i=0;$i<$data->length;$i++){
    $getTag=$data->item($i);
    echo $getTag->nodeValue;
    echo"<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method name is [`getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) (with an S) not `getElementByTagName()`.

Change to:

```
$data=$doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
//                    ^ missing s
```

Comment: Ok i'll try it and let you know :)

Comment: I still get the Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::getElementByTagName() ...
Can you help me on that.

Comment: I can see from your error that you're still not using `getElementsByTagName`. Did you save your changes?

Comment: yes i made the change and am still getting the error..do i have to install any library??

Comment: No library is needed. Maybe you are editing the wrong script or something like that because if you have corrected the function name it will work. Or maybe you have another call somewhere else to the bad function name.